# Censuring a variant reading

Tags: capital-punishment, parashas-emor

In [Leviticus 24:20](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0324.htm#20) we read the phrase "an eye for an eye." The talmud teaches (in Bava Kamma and Ketubot) that this refers to monetary value. Is there any source which criticizes a literal reading?

More than just asserting that money is the point, is there any commentator who outright attacks the opinion that the restitution is literal?

Comment: For reference, this phrase appears in Shemos 21:24, Vayikra 24:20, and Devarim 19:21. The main Gemara is in Bava Kama 84a, where it expounds all three of these pesukim in several different lines of thought that all lead to the same conclusion; Kesuvos 32b and 38a both quote either the conclusion or an exposition from the Gemara in Bava Kama.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by DoubleAA, the Rambam writes ([Hovel uMazik 1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088908/jewish/Chovel-uMazzik-Chapter-One.htm):3)

> The Torah's statement Leviticus 24:20: "[eye for eye ...] Just as he caused an injury to
>   his fellowman, so too, an injury should be caused to him," should not
>   be interpreted in a literal sense. It does not mean that the person
>   who caused the injury should actually be subjected to a similar
>   physical punishment. Instead, the intent is that he deserves to lose a
>   limb or to be injured in the same manner as his colleague was, and
>   therefore he should make financial restitution to him.

then goes to explain it from different verses. He continues in 1:6

> Although these interpretations are obvious from the study of the
>   Written Law, and they are explicitly mentioned in the Oral Tradition
>   transmitted by Moses from Mount Sinai, they are all regarded as
>   halachot from Moses. This is what our ancestors saw in the court of
>   Joshua and in the court of Samuel of Ramah, and in every single Jewish
>   court that has functioned from the days of Moses our teacher until the
>   present age.

The Rambam then goes and describes the five payments made by someone who injures his fellow: pain, unemployment, medical expenses, unemployment and damages.

Comment: Notably, in Moreh Nevuchim when he explains the reasons for mitzvos, he explains "an eye for an eye" in accordance with the literal meaning.